# Add info to the <head> of a specific wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add some link information and a short script to my  on a specific post (post 9597). I am adding the following code to my themes functions.php

```
function chromeextension_head() {
if(is_single( '9597' ))
  ?>
  <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pknhdfeakbecfgahlbdfnjfjgbkgllfo">
        <script>
            function ExtInstall() {
                if (chrome.app.isInstalled) 
                    alert("already installed!");
                else 
                    chrome.webstore.install();
            }
        </script>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'chromeextension_head' );
```

The problem is that now the code shows up on all posts and pages, not just post 9597. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add the html code within {}.

```
function chromeextension_head() {
if(is_single( '9597' )){
  ?>
  <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pknhdfeakbecfgahlbdfnjfjgbkgllfo">
        <script>
            function ExtInstall() {
                if (chrome.app.isInstalled) 
                    alert("already installed!");
                else 
                    chrome.webstore.install();
            }
        </script>
  <?php
} }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'chromeextension_head' );
```

Comment: i reckon this is the answer, OP was missing open/close if tags